# Закрыть всплывающие окно через несколько секунд

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код, в котором всплывает уведомление.
Как сделать автоматическое закрытие этого уведомления через несколько секунд?

HTML:

```
<div id="msg_pop">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  Пример модального окна, всплывающего при загрузке сайта.
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var delay_popup = 0; var msg_pop = 
  document.getElementById('msg_pop'); 
  setTimeout("document.getElementById('msg_pop').style.display='block'; 
  document.getElementById('msg_pop').className += 'fadeIn';", 
  delay_popup); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй тот же setTimeout только вместо значения 'block' поставь 'none'  и задержку 3 секунды.
setTimeout('твой none', 3000);

Answer (score 0):

Загуглите метод setTimeout или почитайте здесь:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это

```
var timer=setInterval(function(){
  var obj1 = document.getElementsByClassName("postcell")
  obj1[0].style.display="none";
  clearInterval(timer);
},5000);
```